# does unnamed namespace linkage is internal or external or a mix

Tags: c++, namespaces, linkage

I was reading a book and I have some ambiguities about linkage into namaspaces.

As far as I read,

> When you are in   a situation where you need to declare global symbols
>   as     statics    to avoid linkage problems,  prefer to use unnamed
>   namespaces

Ok So inside an unnamed namespace what is defined will have internal linkage (like using static in global namespace).

Then the write added :

> Template arguments cannot be names with internal linkage,
>   so using static variables is not possible.

Ok till now.

> On the other hand, symbols in an unnamed namespace **have external linkage** and can be used as template arguments.

So here I am lost, is the content of an unnamed namespace will have internal or external linkage ?

```
#include <iostream>
template <int const& Size>
class test {};

static int Size1 = 10;

namespace
{
    int Size2 = 10;
}  

int main(void)
{
    test<Size1> t1; // said here gonna produce a compile error but was not the case
    test<Size2> t2;

    return 0;
}
```

And what about the case of normale namespace (named namespace).

Thank you.